# LibGDX - TexturePacker2 doesn't generate/pack images

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently reading a book on LibGDX Game Development - [Learning LigbGDX Game Development](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-libgdx-game-development/book).
In the book, we use TexturePacker2 to generate a .png and .pack file to pack a half dozen textures into a texture atlas. I followed the code exactly, but it does not generate anything into the destination folder.
Here is the code in my desktop project folder:

```
package com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2.Settings;

public class Main {
    private static boolean rebuildAtlas = true;
    private static boolean drawDebugOutline = false;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if (rebuildAtlas) {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.maxWidth = 1024;
            settings.maxHeight = 1024;
            settings.debug = drawDebugOutline;
            TexturePacker2.process(settings, "assets-raw/images", "../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images", "canyonbunny.pack");
            TexturePacker2.process(settings, "assets-raw/images-ui", "../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images", "canyonbunny-ui.pack");
            rebuildAtlas = false;
        }

        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "CanyonBunny";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;

        new LwjglApplication(new CanyonBunnyMain(), cfg);
    }
}
```

But when I run this, nothing is generated into my CanyonBunny-android/assets/images folder. The only way I can get my textures to load is to download the sources for the book and put the already generated .png and .pack folder in the correct folder. I followed the book exactly, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I get the logging message that it is generating a 1024x1024 texture atlas, so the code is being executed. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is what the console says when I start the application(with the already-generated files)

```
Packing.........
Writing 1024x1024: ../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images/canyonbunny.png
Packing......
Writing 1024x1024: ../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images/canyonbunny-ui.png
game.Assets: # of assets loaded: 2
game.Assets: asset: images/canyonbunny.pack
game.Assets: asset: images/canyonbunny.png
```

Without the already-generated files:

```
Packing.........
Writing 1024x1024: ../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images/canyonbunny.png
Packing......
Writing 1024x1024: ../CanyonBunny-android/assets/images/canyonbunny-ui.png
game.Assets: Couldn't load asset 'images/canyonbunny.pack'
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: images/canyonbunny.pack (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:97)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureAtlasLoader.getDependencies(TextureAtlasLoader.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureAtlasLoader.getDependencies(TextureAtlasLoader.java:34)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleSyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:103)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:399)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:314)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:337)
    at game.Assets.init(Assets.java:38)
    at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.CanyonBunnyMain.create(CanyonBunnyMain.java:17)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:125)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)
game.Assets: # of assets loaded: 0
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ObjectMap.get(ObjectMap.java:278)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:103)
    at game.Assets.init(Assets.java:45)
    at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.CanyonBunnyMain.create(CanyonBunnyMain.java:17)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:125)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)
```

Comment: maybe post your import statements too

Comment: Sure. Eclipse just crashed. Trying to also get the logs for when I dont use the pregenerated textures. Edit: Imports added

Comment: image pack is generated in assets folder in android project. Make sure images from input path exists, and btw try refresh file explorer :) whats the number of chapter?

Comment: Refreshed, still didn't work. :( We first used the texture packer in chapter 4 for the game textures, such as character and coins. Now I'm in Chpater 7 using it for the menus. The location of the files should be fine since when I put the already generated files in there, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check if the files are actually created in the correct folder using file explorer (not eclipse).
  If you can't find, try searching it and make it appear in the correct folder first.

  The log suggests that the file is being generated, I suppose it should be.
- However, **eclipse does not recognize the newly generated files**. You have to hit refresh in the eclipse project folder before using them.
  Check it it works first.
- Now you won't be able to pack them at each run. I had the same issue, so I created a different project (to be used as a tool) which would do packing (and automate many other little things). Whenever I changed assets, I'd run the tool once before testing.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked my work space and, for some weird reason, my android project isn't in that folder. I have no idea where it is. I'll find it and then move it to workspace, and then try these suggestions.

Comment: Well, the files aren't being found in my destination folder. Which makes me thing that maybe the path may be wrong. Although I checked and everything's fine with it...

Comment: Try giving absolute path to the method call

Comment: That worked. Strange. I had to use an absolute path for every single file. Even my level image, which worked fine before, needed a absolute directory. Thanks though. Now it works. :D Any major downside to using an absolute directory? I know moving workspaces would be an issue. And making it Open Source may lead some confusion.

Comment: Try to make it configurable externally e.g. from a config.properties file.. That should be good enough. If you can fetch current path by some other means and give it to this function, that should work too. Now ask about fetching that path by another method in a new question.. I'll answer you there :P Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using an old version of libgdx — right? `TexturePacker2` isn't there anymore, there's just the `TexturePacker` now (and it works flawlessly, by the way). I'd recommend you updating first.

Comment: Yeah. 0.9.7. The book "highly recommended" using this version for the book. I planned on updating to the latest version for any of my own projects.

Comment: @user2082169 using "real books" on such constantly evolving topics may be a big pain. I suspect, you'd better rely on general Java (and programming) skills, general "science" of developing games, OpenGL stuff and the official libgdx wiki (it has some incomplete areas, but then you can read its source code, it's very good and readable)

Comment: hm, OpenGL is also a funny thing, most books about OpenGL are extremely outdated despite its age (still using immediate mode rendering — glBegin/glEnd, ...)

Comment: Yeah, I've just using books to get me started and then plan to use official sources, docs, etc. I actually just finished a book on OpenGL ES 2.0 called Learning OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android: A Quick Start Guide. Pretty good book actually. Fairly recent too.

Comment: "The type TexturePacker is deprecated" Updated and got this. :) Is there a new way of doing it now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It worked with `drawDebugOutline = true`, but when I changed it to false it crashed.

It is an Eclipse thing...

The solution as hinted at above is to refresh the project.  Eclipse is not seeing the new packed texture file until you refresh.  Right click on the Android project and click "Refresh" which will cause Eclipse to find the new file.